# Select Div in JQuery without selecting the parent Div

Tags: ajax, jquery, parent

I have the following script:

```
$("#border-radius").click(function(){   
var value = $("#border-radius").attr("value");
    $("div.editable").click(function () { 
    mySQLinsert(value, '2', this.id)
     $(this).css({
    "-webkit-border-radius": value
    });  
});
```

});

Basically, the "#border-radius" ID is to a text input. You type in a value, click the textbox (can't figure out a way around this) and then click the div with the class "editable" and it will apply the style "-webkit-border-radius" (I know its not cross-browser), to that DIV.

The mySQLinsert function uses Ajax to send the value of the mySQLinsert function to a mySQL database using a php page (nothing fancy).

**Issue: When I click the child div (div inside of a div) it also applies this value to the parent object, and runs the mySQLinsert function and stored it in the database**

I need to be able to select both the parent, and the child individually depending on which one is clicked.

Comment: I don't quite get it. Do you want to stop bubbling click event?

Comment: I am not sure what that means.

Comment: Basically, if I wrap a div "a" inside of a div "b" and try to apply the border-radius style by clicking on the div "a", it will automatically apply it to div "a" and "b"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stopPropagation()` to prevent the click bubbling up to its parent element.

```
$("#border-radius").click(function(){   
    var value = $("#border-radius").attr("value");
    $("div.editable").click(function (e) { 

       // Note the parameter e passed in the function above
       e.stopPropagation();

       mySQLinsert(value, '2', this.id)
       $(this).css({"-webkit-border-radius": value});  
    });                      
});
```